# Error C3392 'VAL_T': invalid type argument for generic parameter 'T' of generic 'System::Nullable', must have a public parameterless constructor

Tags: generics, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

.h file

```
generic<typename VAL_T> where VAL_T : value class,System::ValueType
    Nullable<VAL_T> Get();
```

.cpp file

```
generic<typename VAL_T> 
Nullable<VAL_T> FidField::Get()
  {
        return Nullable<VAL_T>();
  }
```

When i compile this code i get the following error.

> error C3392: 'VAL_T': invalid type argument for generic
>   parameter 'T' of generic 'System::Nullable', must have a public
>   parameterless constructor

I am not getting any error in visual studio 2010(vc10) and 2012(vc110).

I am not sure where to add constructor. Can someone please help.
Thanks in advance.

**Update**:

i see that the Nullable object interface has been changed in current .Net framework.
current version:

```
generic<typename T>
where T : value struct, gcnew()
[SerializableAttribute]
public value struct Nullable
```

in vs2010:

```
generic<typename T>
where T : value class
public value class Nullable
```

So i added gcnew() which the Nullable class expects. I still get the same error.

**Reference links**:
[Nullable in current .Net framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

[Nullable in .Net framework 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to generic typename changes of Nullable in .NET framework 4.5.

I made generic type to be of `value struct, gcnew()`

i added `where VAL_T : value class,System::ValueType, gcnew()` in both header and cpp files. This solved the issue.